# Collapsing Levels of a Factor Variable in one column while summing the counts in another

Tags: r, forcats

I originally had a vary wide data (4 rows with 158 columns) which I used `reshape::melt()` on to create a long data set (624 rows x 3 columns).

Now, however, I have a data set like this:

```
   demo <- data.frame(region = as.factor(c("North", "South", "East", "West")),
                       criteria = as.factor(c("Writing_1_a", "Writing_2_a", "Writing_3_a", "Writing_4_a", 
                                              "Writing_1_b", "Writing_2_b", "Writing_3_b", "Writing_4_b")), 
                       counts = as.integer(c(18, 27, 99, 42, 36, 144, 99, 9)))
```

Which produces a table similar to the one below:

```
     region   criteria      counts
     North    Writing_1_a       18
     South    Writing_2_a       27
     East     Writing_3_a       99
     West     Writing_4_a       42
     North    Writing_1_b       36
     South    Writing_2_b      144
     East     Writing_3_b       99
     West     Writing_4_b        9
```

Now what I want to create is something like this:

```
goal <- data.frame(region = as.factor(c("North", "South", "East", "West")),
                   criteria = as.factor(c("Writing_1", "Writing_2", "Writing_3", "Writing_4")), 
                   counts = as.integer(c(54, 171, 198, 51)))
```

Meaning that when I collapse the criteria columns it sums the counts:

```
region  criteria     counts
North   Writing_1        54
South   Writing_2       171
East    Writing_3       198
West    Writing_4        51
```

I have tried using `forcats::fct_collapse` and `forcats::recode()`but to no avail - I'm positive I'm just not doing it right. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about what exactly you're trying to do to change factor levels—`fct_collapse` would manually collapse several levels into one level, and `fct_recode` would manually change the labels of individual levels. What you're trying to do is change all the labels based on applying some function, in which case `fct_relabel` is appropriate.

You can write out an anonymous function when you call `fct_relabel`, or just pass it the name of a function and that function's argument(s). In this case, you can use `stringr::str_remove` to find and remove a regex pattern, and regex such as `_[a-z]$` to remove any underscore and then lowercase letter that appear at the end of a string. That way it should scale well with your real data, but you can adjust it if not.

```r
library(tidyverse)
...
new_crits <- demo %>%
  mutate(crit_no_digits = fct_relabel(criteria, str_remove, "_[a-z]$"))

new_crits
#>   region    criteria counts crit_no_digits
#> 1  North Writing_1_a     18      Writing_1
#> 2  South Writing_2_a     27      Writing_2
#> 3   East Writing_3_a     99      Writing_3
#> 4   West Writing_4_a     42      Writing_4
#> 5  North Writing_1_b     36      Writing_1
#> 6  South Writing_2_b    144      Writing_2
#> 7   East Writing_3_b     99      Writing_3
#> 8   West Writing_4_b      9      Writing_4
```

Verifying that this new variable has only the levels you want:

```r
levels(new_crits$crit_no_digits)
#> [1] "Writing_1" "Writing_2" "Writing_3" "Writing_4"
```

And then summarizing based on that new factor:

```r
new_crits %>%
  group_by(crit_no_digits) %>%
  summarise(counts = sum(counts))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   crit_no_digits counts
#>   <fct>           <int>
#> 1 Writing_1          54
#> 2 Writing_2         171
#> 3 Writing_3         198
#> 4 Writing_4          51
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I was missing that last bit of code: `group_by` and then `summarise`. Thank you so much for getting me the rest of the way there :)

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr solution using regular expressions:

```
demo %>% 
  mutate(criteria = gsub("(_a)|(_b)", "", criteria)) %>%
  group_by(region, criteria) %>% 
  summarize(counts = sum(counts)) %>% 
  arrange(criteria) %>% 
  as.data.frame

  region  criteria counts
1  North Writing_1     54
2  South Writing_2    171
3   East Writing_3    198
4   West Writing_4     51
```